# creating simple web browser in Monodroid

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.android

Is it possible to create a simple web browser for Android by using Monodroid? My objective is to create a browser that can display (lets say) sites like google.com. C# is my preferred language and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate (monodroid has been integrated with it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to build webbrowser? Did you check WebView control? - should be good enough to display websites on android.

Comment: Yeah someone told me about it, using it now. Thanks for replying.